# Is it possible to know which app is running in foreground of a iOS device when our app is in background?

Tags: ios, ios8

For example: let's say that the user is using the Facebook app, is it possible to know for another app in the same device (which is running in background) that the Facebook app is running in the foreground?

Comment: App store or Jailbroken?

Comment: And I think the answer is "no" for App Store.

Comment: What's the point? Under normal circumstances, your app won't be running enough in the background to know what the user is doing in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul mentioned, you cannot find out which app is running in the foreground while you are in the background.